# Receiving AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve' when using pulp

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, linear-programming, pulp

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to plot linear programming equations on Jupyter Notebook using `Pulp`.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve'
```

Context:
[image: img]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you did try before posting. Also, it is not a good idea to insert images to display text. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Comment: I have never been using this library but have you defined the default solver ?
From the docs I see that, you need to setup the solvers, or pass it as argument to the `solve` 
https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_configure_solvers.html

Comment: or just call `prob.setSolver()` before calling `prob.solve()` it will set default solver.`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, installing Pulp using easy_install did not install default solver. I had to uninstall Pulp using `pip uninstall pulp` and then reinstalled using `pip install pulp`.
Use the following to see if it installed any solver.

```
import pulp as pl
solver_list = pl.listSolvers(onlyAvailable=True)
```